# Reactjs: replacing div(dynamicaly populated have same class) onclick with new div for only clicked element

Tags: reactjs

```
getData(){ 
  return ( 
  <div class="firstGen" onClick={this.handleRetrive}> some elements </div> 
  <div class="firstGen" onClick={this.handleRetrive}> some elements </div> 
  <div class="firstGen" onClick={this.handleRetrive}> some elements </div> 
  <div class="firstGen" onClick={this.handleRetrive}> some elements </div> 
 ); 
} 
handleRetrive(e) { 
  return( <div id="SecondGen"> some other elements </div> 
 ); 
} 
render()
{ 
  return( 
  <div> some elements <div id="main">{this.getData}> some text</div> </div> 
   ); 
 }
```

/* I displayed id=main element perfectly and i just what to replace .firstGen with #SecondGen on click of .firstGen.(only the clicked element from list of all elements having class = firstGen) NOTE: cannot use state variables due to complications in my code. */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return arguments from onClick(there's nothing to catch that response).

What you'd want it to change to state inside the `handleRetrive` function, the state can be what HTML to show inside the render.

In any case, the flow has to be like this:

1. Catch onClick
2. Modify state.
3. State change will trigger the render function, Use the state to decide what to render.

You can read about conditional rendering here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: If i used the state change on clicking one of the .firstGen element, all the .firstGen elements are changed to secondGen rather than what I have clicked.

Comment: Sounds like each firstGen is a component with his own state... you need to manage this logic somewhere, but it will still be state based

Comment: Can you suggest any logic for that

Answer (score 0):

You're not invoking the `getData` method. Try `this.getData()`.